# i could not be able to run my drone inside building (gps no fix)

Tags: dronekit-python, dronekit

"I have a Pixhawk 2.4.8 drone. I want to automate this drone using Linux and Python code instead of remote control. I have been able to do this successfully in an open and empty area, but my goal is to use the drone in a warehouse. I think I couldn't succeed due to security reasons or because the drone cannot detect GPS signals. If anyone has experience in this area, can they help me? I want to fly the drone in a warehouse and control it with Python (3) (e.g., take off, land, move right, move left, etc.). If I need to deactivate the security feature for this or if I need to purchase any additional devices, I can act accordingly based on the guidance. I am seeking advice as I have no knowledge in this area."

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.